# Why can't Selenium find the table in this website?

Tags: html, python-3.x, pandas, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a table that appears in a new website when you fulfill a form, but it raises a ValueError: No tables found. You can see the code details below:

```py
ANS_TabNetMLR_URL = navegador.get("http://www.ans.gov.br/anstabnet/cgi-bin/dh?dados/tabnet_rc.def")
selecionarLinha = Select(navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="L"]'))
selecionarLinhaOperadora = selecionarLinha.select_by_visible_text('Operadora')

selecionarColuna = Select(navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="C"]'))
selecionarColunaModalidade = selecionarColuna.select_by_visible_text('Grupo Modalidade')

selecionarConteudo = Select(navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="I"]'))
selecionarConteudo.deselect_by_visible_text('Receita de contraprestações')
selecionarConteudoMLR = selecionarConteudo.select_by_visible_text('Despesa assistencial')

selecionarMostra = navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="geral"]/thead/tr[2]/td[2]/center/form/table[2]/tbody/tr[4]/td/p[2]/input[1]').click()

novaURL = 'http://www.ans.gov.br/anstabnet/cgi-bin/tabnet?dados/tabnet_rc.def'
aguardar = WebDriverWait(navegador, 10).until(ec.url_to_be(novaURL))

encontrarTabela = navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="geral"]/thead/tr[2]/td[2]/center/table/tbody')

HTML_tabela_MLR = encontrarTabela.get_attribute('outerHTML')
sopa = BeautifulSoup(HTML_tabela_MLR, 'html.parser')

tabela = sopa.find(name = 'table border')
df_completo_MLR = pd.DataFrame()

lista_completa_MLR=pd.read_html(str(tabela),index_col=('Operadora'), header=(0), thousands='.')
```

And so the console output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\vitor.dias\Documents\ANSMLR.py", line 206, in <module>
    lista_completa_MLR=pd.read_html(str(tabela),index_col=('Operadora'), header=(0), thousands='.')

  File "C:\Users\vitor.dias\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\vitor.dias\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1113, in read_html
    return _parse(

  File "C:\Users\vitor.dias\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 939, in _parse
    raise retained

  File "C:\Users\vitor.dias\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 919, in _parse
    tables = p.parse_tables()

  File "C:\Users\vitor.dias\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 239, in parse_tables
    tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)

  File "C:\Users\vitor.dias\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 569, in _parse_tables
    raise ValueError("No tables found")

ValueError: No tables found
```

I'm grateful since now for any help and I'm sorry if it's too dumb LOL I'm just starting on the Stackoverflow and using Selenium.

I've tried to scrape a table through its HTML to transform it on dataframe in Pandas, but then it couldn't find the table, even that I could see it doing this process manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Suggested solution:** I don't think you need bs4 at all here - you should try

```py
tableEl = navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, '//center/table')
tableHtml = tableEl.get_attribute('outerHTML')

lista_completa_MLR=pd.read_html(tableHtml) # ,index_col=('Operadora'), header=(0), thousands='.')
# [I recommend trying without extra arguments first; if it works, try again with all arguments.]
```

---

---

**Explanation[s]:** There are a few things I feel the need to point out about your code:

- there is no need to use `BeautifulSoup` on `outerHTML` only to stringify the soup [it's redundant]
- `table border` is not a tag name [I don't think tag names can have spaces in them]. `table` is the tag name and `border` is an [attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp), so `.find(name = 'table border')` is pretty much guaranteed to always return `None`. The correct way would have been

> ```py
> tabela = sopa.find(name='table', attrs={'border': ''})
> ```
>
> or, with [CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) [which I prefer]:
>
> ```py
> tabela = sopa.select('table[border=""]')
> ```
>
> **However**, this would still return `None` since

- the table needs to be **inside** `encontrarTabela`, but `encontrarTabela` has *already gone inside the table!*

> [image: the table you want]
>
> [`tbody` is inside the table], so `str(tabela)` will just be `"None"` for two separate reasons, and

- for `pd.read_html` to work, there needs to be at least one `table` tag in the input

---

> Why can't Selenium find the table in this website?

Given that the code ran without errors before the last line in the snippet, I'd say that Selenium *did* find the table. It was *Pandas* that couldn't find the table, because there *were no table tags* to find in the input that was passed to `read_html`

Comment: Thanks for the help! The point on BeautifulSoup is in virtue to the dynamic table presence that it would be different regarding to the options selected on the forms, I thought it wouldn't find the table so it won't return the HTML desired, something that sometimes happens. That table border was a try to get the table without using .find(name = tbody), what I was trying to do in the first place and thanks to you I understood why didn't work haha.